# how to wrap text while keeping border in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

so I've created a snippet of layout that I'd like to re-use in various places in my code. JSFiddle with what it looks like normally with the following dom structure: https://jsfiddle.net/64x9udcr/

```
<a class="stamp">
    <div class="stamp-left"><span>0023f23f2</span></div>
    <div class="stamp-right"><span>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</span></div>
</a>
```

Basicly an identifier on the left, with a description on the right, not too complicated. It's also inline, so it can be included in a line of text like an identifier.
Ex: [image]

What I'm having trouble with is getting it to wrap if necessary. The following is an image of what I'd like to happen when wrapping is needed. A would be preferred, but if not possible, then B. 
[image]

Any pointers as to what combination of CSS I should be using?

Comment: Just so you know some of us are in office environments that block imgur so if you can find an alternative source for your images, that would be great.

Comment: @JonP considering Stack Exchange uses Imgur's API for its uploads, I feel sorry for you.

Answer (score 1):

Used flex method with few little changes in your code.

https://jsfiddle.net/64x9udcr/2/

```css
.label,
.stamp {
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: inline;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 0.2em 0.6em 0.3em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.stamp {
  border: 1px solid rgb(218, 218, 218);
  color: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
  padding: 0;
}

.stamp .stamp-left,
.stamp .stamp-right {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
}

.stamp .stamp-left {
  background: rgb(218, 218, 218) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  font-family: "courier";
}

.select2-results__option--highlighted .stamp .stamp-left {
  color: rgb(51, 122, 183);
}

a.stamp:hover {
  border-color: rgb(35, 82, 124);
}

a.stamp:hover .stamp-left {
  background-color: rgb(35, 82, 124);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

a.stamp:hover .stamp-right {
  color: rgb(35, 82, 124);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.stamp {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <a class="stamp">
    <div class="stamp-left"><span>0023f23f2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="stamp-right"><span>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```